# display rectangles based on values

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to draw rectangle size based on the values. I want to draw bigger rectangle if the value is more and relatively smaller size if the value is lesser.

My code:

```
var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
                        .data(filtereddata)
                        .enter().append("rect")
                        .attr("id", function(d,i) { console.log(d); return d.instancegroup;  })
                        .attr("rx",3)
                        .attr("ry",3)
                        .style("fill", function(d,i) { return "#01DF01";})
                        .attr("x", function(d,i) { return i * 80; })
                        .attr("width",function (d,i){
                            if (d.value < 80)
                            {
                                return 40;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return d.value/4; 
                            }

                        })
                        .on("click",function(d,i) { console.log(d);})
                        .attr("y", function(d) { return 40; })
                        .attr("height", function(d) { 
                            if (d.value < 80)
                            {
                                return 15;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return d.value/5; 
                            }
                            })
```

However the spacing between the rectangles does not work properly. Is there a better way to resolve this.[image]

I tried with axis too but didnt work. I was getting wrong to align the x-axis.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
            width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
 var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(filtereddata)
                    .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("id", function(d,i) { console.log(d); return d.instancegroup;  })
                    .attr("rx",3)
                    .attr("ry",3)
                    .style("fill", function(d,i) { return "#01DF01";})
.attr("x", function (d,i) { 

                            if(i ==0 )
                            {
                                return 40;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return x(d.value) + 100 ;
                            }

                            })
                        .attr("y", function (d,i) { return  40;})
                        .attr("width", function (d,i) { return height - y(d.value);})
                        .attr("height", function (d,i) { console.log(x(d.value)); return height - y(d.value);})
```

The data :

```
[{"status: "Up",value: "300"},{"status: "Up",value: "200"},{"status: "Up",value: "35"}]
```

Comment: In order to help you fixing what *does not work properly* you need to tell us how you would like the spacing to look like.

Comment: the spacing similar to the image attached.The horizontal spacing should be uniform. The size of the rectangle should be corresponding to the value (both the height and width) along with the horizontal spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `x` positions are accumulated using widths of previous rectangles having varying dimensions, I'd pre-calculate these values and attach them to the objects prior to binding the data array via d3:

```js
var SPACING = 20;

var data = [
    {"status": "Up", value: "300"},
    {"status": "Up", value: "200"},
    {"status": "Up", value: "35"}
];


data.forEach(function(d, i, array) {
    d.width = d.value < 80 ? 40 : d.value / 4;
    d.height = d.value < 80 ? 15 : d.value / 5;
    d.x = i == 0 ? 0 : array[i-1].x + array[i-1].width + SPACING;
    d.y = 40;
});
```

Later on you are able to directly access these properties without the need for further calculations:

```
var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(filtereddata)
                .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr({
                        "id": function (d, i) { return d.instancegroup; },
                        "rx": 3,
                        "ry": 3,
                        "x": function (d) { return d.x; },
                        "y": function (d) { return d.y; },
                        "width": function (d) { return d.width; },
                        "height": function (d) { return d.height; }
                    })
                    .on("click", function (d) {
                        console.log(d);
                    })
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                        return "#01DF01";
                    })
```